# ImageButton onclick

Tags: java, android

When I click restart button, it creates blue coloured thing. How to set that blue coloured thing to transparent? Please help me.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgWwW.png]

Comment: share your code and screenshot..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgWwW.png

Comment: Your code??????

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The question need some more details. 
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/ibtn_restart" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your image in `android:src` and set the background as null to remove the visual feedback:

`android:background="@null"`

Please note that this will remove the visual feedback for button press and is not recommended. Use a selector to set different images depending on the button state for better UX

Answer (score 0):

use `ImageView` Instead of `ImageButton`

```
 <ImageView
android:layout_width="120dp" 
android:layout_height="130dp"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" 
android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground" android:id="@+id/ibtn_restart" />
```

and in  Java file

```
ImageView ibtn_restart=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ibtn_restart);
```

Comment: Unfortunately,Guess Who? has stopped.

Comment: post errro ciode

Comment: there is no error code but it launch, freeze  and this comes Unfortunately,Guess Who? has stopped

Comment: change in both files Java As well as xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "Button", try using "selector" as background(android:background="@drawable/button_selector").
A sample selector -> button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```